# concatenating strings using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

This is a program to concatenate strings using `malloc`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *sconcat(char *ptr1,char *ptr2);

void main()
{
char string1[20],string2[20],*ptr;
clrscr();

printf("enter string 1: ");
gets(string1);

printf("enter string 2: ");
gets(string2);

ptr=sconcat(string1,string2);

printf("output string : %s",ptr);
getch();
}

char *sconcat(char *ptr1,char *ptr2)
{
int len1,len2,i,j;
char *ptr3;

len1=strlen(ptr1);
len2=strlen(ptr2);

ptr3=(char *)malloc((len1+len2+1)*sizeof(char));

for(i=0;ptr1[i]!='\0';i++)
ptr3[i]=ptr1[i];

j=i;i=0;
for(;ptr2[j]!='\0';j++,i++)
ptr3[j]=ptr2[i];

ptr3[j]='\0';
return(ptr3);
}

output:
enter string 1 : this program does
enter string 2 : not give output
output string : this program does
```

What correction is needed to concatenate strings. When I use `char string1[20],string2[20],*ptr;` after `void main()`,

```
output:
enter string 1 : is this 
enter string 2 : correct ?
output string : correct? ?
```

Comment: The return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`.  You will find greater portability with `size_t len1,len2,i,j`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test in your second `for` loop is incorrect; it should be `ptr2[i] != '\0'`, not `ptr2[j] != '\0'`.

Several remarks on the code:

- [Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1600898)
- `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so multiplying by `sizeof(char)` only makes the code harder to read.
- Declare the parameters of `sconcat` as `const char *`, since they're not modifying the strings they receive.
- `malloc` can return NULL; you must handle that case in your program, for example by displaying an error message and exiting.
- `gets` is unsafe and will crash your program if the user enters more characters than were allocated. Replace `gets(string)` with `fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin)`, and getting rid of the trailing newline.
- `clrscr()` and `getch()`, as well as the infamous `<conio.h>` header, are not standard C and are non-portable; avoid them in simple programs like this one.

Comment: thanx...its working now....if not `clrscr()` and `getch()`, `<conio.h>` header,then how which statements must replace them?

Comment: if i declare string length as 10 instead of 20, i get `output:enter string 1: i love ; enter string 2 : my india ; output string : i love m` ....does not work

Comment: @user4815162342 Substituting `gets()` with `fgets()`, though a good idea has a side effect: `fgets()` retains the '\n'.  `gets()` does not.  An closer alternative is `gets_s()`.

Comment: instead of `gets` i have used`fgets(stdin, string1, sizeof(string1)); gives error1:`type mismatch in parameter '_n' in call to 'fgets'`; error 2:`type mismatch in parameter '_n' in call to 'fgets'` and using `gets_s` gives `undefined symbol _gets_s`

Comment: @chux Good point, I've now amended the answer to mention the trailing newline. `gets_s` only made it to C11, and is still not available on many systems - for example, my fairly up-to-date ArchLinux doesn't have a manpage for `gets_s`, nor is it present in the system include files.

Comment: @user3018725 re `fgets` my answer switched the order of arguments - I've now updated the answer with the correct order.

Comment: @user3018725 re `clrscr` and friends, my point is that they are non-portable (they won't work on Linux or Mac), and that you don't need them in such a simple program. If you refrain from manipulating the "console", your program will remain usable from pipelines, where the standard input and/or the standard output are redirected to a file or to another program.

Answer (score 3):

You can more simply use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

```
printf("enter string 1: ");
gets(string1);

printf("enter string 2: ");
gets(string2);

strcat(string1,string2);
```

It would, however, change `string1` so you might want to use `strcpy` too (to copy `string1` to another string and then return it).

Comment: i know about `strcat` but i want to accomplish it this way.

Comment: Given OP's `char string1[20],string2[20]`, "enter string 1 : this program does" and "enter string 2 : not give output", the suggested `strcat(string1,string2)` writes outside `string1[]`.